# How to get Fragment view holder Object

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

Hello i create class that implement `BottomSheetDialogFragment` with dynamic content. The content is a `Fragment`. So when initialize the `BottomSheet` i passing fragment object, and attach it to specific Container ID inside this `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. Looks like this :

```
private fun attachContentFragment() {
        val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.apply {
            replace(R.id.flContent, state.layoutContent)
            commit()
        }
}
```

`state.layoutContent` is my attached Fragment

I need to dismiss the `BottomSheet` if every action called in that fragment.
As far as i know, i need to get the object of BottomSheet that hold me(Fragment) and dismiss it.

But how i can get that BottomSheet object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, technically it is a `fragment` inside `fragment` situation. I think there is several solutions here:

1. Call `Activity` from your child `fragment`. `BottomSheetDialogFragment` will subscribe to `Activity` for such events and react on them.
2. Get the instance of a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` by calling proper `FragmentManager` (which possible is an `Activity` one). You can get an instance of a fragment `byTag` for example.
3. Or you can call `getParentFragment` from a child `Fragment`.